# Cleaning up after a conflicted git merge?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, merge-conflict-resolution, filemerge

I had a small conflict in a `.h` header file in a project I'm working on. This project is tracked in Git.

Fortunately, the conflict was very simple to solve. I used

`git mergetool`

And chose the default (`opendiff`) which seemed to be FileMerge on my Mac. I made the appropriate changes, saved the file, and closed.

Git then asked me if the merge was successful, I said yes:

`Was the merge successful? [y/n] y`

But now, I have:

```
> git st
# On branch develop
# Changes to be committed:
#   modified:   MyHeader.h
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   MyHeader.h.BACKUP.52920.h
#   MyHeader.h.BASE.52920.h
#   MyHeader.h.LOCAL.52920.h
#   MyHeader.h.REMOTE.52920.h
#   MyHeader.h.orig
```

Which of those extra junk conflict files were created by FileMerge, and which by Git?

***And more importantly:*** How do I remove them?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can simply delete them like you would any other file. For example:

```
rm MyHeader.h.orig
```

Alternatively, if there are no other untracked files, then after you commit with

```
git commit -a
```

you may clean your repository with

```
git clean -n
git clean -f
```

`git clean -n` will tell you what `git clean -f` will do, so you can be sure it's what you want.

Comment: Thanks - `git clean -n/-f` has been the go-to for a long time. You can also specify a path at the end, if you only want to perform the clean on a subfolder.

Comment: Sometimes *.orig is in the **.gitignore** file. In this case the way to go is dry-run including ignored files: `git clean -nx */*.orig`, check and then delete `git clean -fx */*.orig`.
Credit goes to: http://travisjeffery.com/b/2011/12/keeping-your-git-repo-clean-of-orig-files/

Answer (score 9):

If they are the only untracked files, you can use `git clean` to delete them. Run it once with the `-n` flag to see what will be deleted then if you are sure, run it with `-f`. Don't use it if you have untracked files you want to keep!

Comment: Note: "if they are the only untracked files". Be very careful with `git clean`, as you could easily lose the very files that are not under version control! I'd recommend just removing them manually.

Comment: Or, I've gotten into the habit of using a file pattern, like: `git clean -f *.orig`

Answer (score 1):

First commit your merge.

Once you're satisfied that all is well, simply remove these extra files manually (using `rm <filename>`, for example).